# Creating a frame for a view with gradient in xml

Tags: android, xml, view, graphics, gradient

I would like to know how to create a kind of gradient frame for a background rectangle with xml.

It's simple to create a background gradient for 1 side with xml definition like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient 
  android:type="linear"
  android:centerX="8%" 
  android:startColor="#FF004D4D" 
  android:centerColor="#FF000000" 
  android:endColor="#FF000000" 
  android:angle="180"/>
</shape>
```

which results into a background like this:

[image: Gradient on the right side]

But how can I create a similar gradient for all sides ? So that it would look something like this (apologies for 30 seconds photoshopping):

[image: Gradient on all sides]

I tried to create a `layer-list`, as suggested in other questions regarding multiple gradients, but that didn't seem to work, it just took the "last item", and used those settings..

I am using `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_bg);` in onDraw method for View if that is of any importance. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was indeed `layered-list`. The mistake was just not lowering the alpha on the `endColor`. So this works as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item> 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <gradient
            android:type="linear"
            android:centerX="8%"
            android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
            android:centerColor="#00FF0000" 
            android:endColor="#00000000"
            android:angle="0"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item> 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <gradient
            android:type="linear"
            android:centerX="8%"
            android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
            android:centerColor="#00FF0000" 
            android:endColor="#00000000"
            android:angle="90"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```